# How to hide tab bar for a specific scene in React Native (react-native-router-flux)?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to hide a whole tab bar for the specific page on my app.
I have tried to hide it on the routing and inside the container too. 
But, it did not work. I could hide header navbar in both scenarios but it is not working 
for tabBar.
Below are my attempt codes:

```
     <Scene
        key="showBarcodeScanner"
        hideNavBar
        hideTabBar
        {...DefaultProps.navbarProps}
        iosStatusbar="light-content"
        component={BarcodeScan}
      />
```

Below method did not work either

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: null,
    tabBarVisible: false
  });
```

I have checked the source and there is a logic to hide the tab (did not go deep though).

```
if (navigationParams.hideTabBar != null) {
  if (navigationParams.hideTabBar) {
    res.tabBarVisible = false;
  }
} else if (hideTabBar) {
  res.tabBarVisible = false;
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there any other method to hide the tabbar for a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

See [Readme](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/README.md) of React Native Router.

```
Actions.refresh({key: 'showBarcodeScanner', hideNavBar: true, hideTabBar: true});
```

Hope it help, u can put any PARAMS you want to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after some research.

The Scene I wanted to hide was inside the Stack which was under the Tabs in my routes.
And without shuffling navigators below code does not work based on official source: 
[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens)

```
tabBarVisible: false
```

I just created a new Stack above my Tabs and the problem is solved.